# Excel VBA Errors while trying to extract emails addresses from a list

Tags: excel

While trying to extract email addresses from a spreadsheet in which the cells contain additional information (according to instructions at https://smallbusiness.chron.com/extract-email-addresses-excel-spreadsheet-42777.html) I entered:

```
Function ExtractCellEmail(cell As Range) As String

    Dim contents As String contents = cell.Text

    AtPosition = InStr(1, contents, "@")
    AddressStartingPosition = InStrRev(contents, " ", AtPosition)
    AddressEndingPosition = InStr(AtPosition, contents, " ")
    AddressEndingPosition = InStr(AtPosition, contents, " ")
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = emailAddress

End Function
```

I received an error message that says

> "Expected: end of statement"

For the sub function I entered

```
Sub Troyextract()
Sub mcrExtractColumnAddresses()

    Do
        Call ExtractEmails(ActiveCell)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

End Sub
```

I received an error message that said

> "Expected End Sub"

Please help.

Troy

Comment: You have `Sub Troyextract()` then on the next line `Sub mcrExtractColumnAddresses()`... you can't have those two

Comment: That doesn't look like a reputable site either from the quality of the code unfortunately.

Comment: `Dim contents As String contents = cell.Text` turn you create an error. Additionally, in the sub function you use two sub names

Comment: To piggy back on @Error1004's comment, while I don't personally like this way - you can keep that on one line by adding a colon, `Dim contents As String: contents = cell.Text`  Also what does the input data look like, you can likely pull just the email address out in a single line...

Answer (score 0):

Does this need to be VBA? You can do this with a formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("@",A1)),TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1&" ",FIND("@",A1))-1)," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1))),"")
```